# Examples of Hyperbolic Groups

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

We already have the Milnor-Svarc Lemma, which tells us that if a group acts "nicely" on a space, then the Cayley graph of the group is quasi-isometric to the given space.  This gives us a lot of hyperbolic groups, because hyperbolic manifolds are ubiquitous.

Edit: For example, the MS-lemma tells us that the surface groups are hyperbolic.

Edit:

Of course, in the large-scale geometric setting here, we consider two metric spaces equivalent if they are quasi-isometric.

There is a result of Kharlampovich and Myasnikov, in "Hyperbolic groups and free constructions" which allows us to construct a "separated HNN extension" of two hyperbolic groups to yield a hyperbolic group.

What are some other ways of constructing word-hyperbolic groups?

Comment: The "easiest" examples of discrete hyperbolic groups are finite groups. For more interesting examples generalising the modular group above see Fuchsian groups.

Comment: Okay, are there other "easy" ways to find non-trivial quasi-isometric equivalence classes of hyperbolic groups?

Comment: A similar question was asked on MathOverflow recently. The [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337738/examples-of-hyperbolic-groups/337748#337748) of Genevois is pretty comprehensive. Regarding the Kharlampovich-Myasnikov result, Bestvina-Feighn's [combination theorem](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214447806) has a similar flavour (although I've never found a way to apply it, while I have applied the Kharlampovich-Myasnikov result).

Comment: Also, why does this have a close vote? It would be helpful if the voter gave some helpful criticism.

Comment: The MathOverflow answer is just what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: In fact, the "geometric" action of $SL(2,Z)$ on the upper half-plane **does not** tell you that $SL(2,Z)$ is hyperbolic. But you can conclude hyperbolicity by observing that this group is commensurable with the free group of rank 2.

Comment: if your definition of "geometric" is "proper and cocompact", we have to agree that $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ does not act geometrically on the upper half plane.

Comment: The point about geometric is important because in higher dimensions you can have a super nice action on hyperbolic space, but if it isn't cocompact it might not be hyperbolic (fundamental group of hyperbolic 3-manifolds with toral cusps for example).

Comment: @PaulPlummer Could it be stated heuristically that "if growth is not behaved well enough, we could end up with noncyclic infinite abelian subgroups"? (And having a rank 2 or higher abelian subgroup implies non-hyperbolic.)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean to be honest

Comment: @PaulPlummer Perhaps your "point about geometric" statement is consistent with the statement "without cocompactness, we could wind up with things that are too big (e.g., the ratio of area to perimeter of triangles) to fit into a hyperbolic setting"?

Comment: I meant that I not really sure if I knew what you mean by "growth not well behaved" or just "growth" and still don't. It might make sense but I don't know from what you have said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A similar question was asked on MathOverflow recently. The [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/337748/35478) of Genevois is pretty comprehensive.